# CSS Border alpha not working

Tags: css, border, alpha

I just dont understand how this doesn't work. The border in the example below should be transparent so that one can see the text under it.

As it is by my case: setting the border's alpha to 0 makes it white. Here it becomes black.

https://jsfiddle.net/taqqcu5j/

```
// Altought this is not a must, i need it to make a visual illusion perfect.

<p>TEXT</p>

<div class='thisElement'></div>
```

CSS

```
.thisElement{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#000;
  border:100px solid rgba(255,255,0,.5);
}

P{
  position:absolute;
  font-size:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use background-clip on the element. If you don't use background-clip the border inherits the background color and then applies the border-color.
https://jsfiddle.net/a2bxzk7z/

```
.thisElement {
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The border color of an element is affected by the background if the border is not completely solid and opaque or background-clip is not border-box.

In your case, the background is black. Change the property of background-clip to `padding-box` will fix this. The default property for background-clip is border-box.

> The background-clip property specifies the painting area of the background.

There are three possible values for this property.

- border-box: Default value. The background is clipped to the border box
- padding-box: The background is clipped to the padding box
- content-box: The background is clipped to the content box

Reference

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp